# Customized crud application service with aspnetboilerplate/abp

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

I have some complex sql queries and views and would like to make a custom Crud Application Service for these queries/views. Does aspnetboilerplate/abp allow you to do this? Does anyone know how?

```
public class TaskAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<Task, TaskDto, int, GetAllTasksInput, CreateTaskInput, UpdateTaskInput>
{
    public TaskAppService(IRepository<Task> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {

    }

    protected override IQueryable<Task> CreateFilteredQuery(GetAllTasksInput input)
    {
        return MAGIC("SELECT * FROM VIEWA LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON... WHERE B.X="+input.FILTERA");
    }
}
```

please ignore query security, it is for illustrative purposes only. I want something like this using AsyncCrudAppService. I plan to take advantage of filtering and sorting.

Comment: What do yoy mean for "make a custom"? Why don't you extends `AsyncCrudAppService` with a `MyAppAsyncCrudAppService` and then you extend `TaskAppService` from `MyAppAsyncCrudAppService`?

Comment: hello. I intend to make custom SQL queries, without using the Abp repositories. But I intend to benefit from filtering and sorting (PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto). Something like that, but with aspnetboilerplate (Abp.Application.Services/ AsyncCrudAppService). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804547/execute-complex-raw-sql-query-in-ef6

Comment: Hi @Gianpiero , Any idea?

Comment: Did you try to study the source code of the class and start from it? By the way when I did it I saw stuff like PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto works with linq. So probably you will not be easily able to use it with direct SQL. Changing you method by using linq maybe the right way